# C# API always return Error 400 Bad Request Angular/Electron app

Tags: c#, angular, api, electron, http-status-code-400

This is my first time asking a question here.

I have a problem with my **Web API server in C#**.

I explain, I have an application in **Angular**, under Electron (not developed by me) which makes API calls.

When I start my API server, all requests return **400 error (Bad request)**. APIs call don't reach the code, nor the Middleware that I tried to develop. I also set the CORS to allow access to all origins or all methods. **APIs run fine in a browser or with Postman**.

> Here it's my API server configuration. I tried a lot of different things and I don't think that's the problem.

```
services.AddCors(options => { 
     options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => {
           policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
     }
}

//...
//further in code
//...

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(CorsMiddleware));
```

After several tries, I found that queries run correctly when in Chrome dev tools when I disable manual user-agent selection. In Chrome Dev', when you go to Settings -> More tools -> Network conditions. The "**Select automatically**" condition of the User-Agent is activated and all request return **400 (Bad Request)**, when **I desactivate it, all requests return 200 OK**.

[automatic user agent selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htdip.png)

This is the only way for queries to run correctly. Is there a solution knowing that I don't have a hand on the Angular code. Is this blocked by **Electron**?
Do I need to add something in the configuration of my API server ? Maybe to open to all User-Agent ?

Thanks

Comment: did you properly configure the ssl?

Comment: I haven't configured anything for SSL. I created a self hosted webapi, maybe I need to add a configuration in Kestrel ? (I don't need to use Https). Actually, i only have : `webHostBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:8090").UseKestrel();`

Comment: I did some research and i had a logger on Kestrel. Kestrel throw an exception : "BadHttpRequestException: Malformed request: invalid headers". I guess it's the "User-agent" header. It works with Postman (with the same user agent) but something goes wrong with server. Is it possible to work around this error knowing that i don't have control over the client ?